# Insert a row with NULL values from one table

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.relacion AS
   (id integer,
    codpadre character varying,
    codhijo character varying,
    canpres numeric(7,3),
    cancert numeric(7,3),--this is usually NULL
    posicion smallint);
```

After that, I need another type from `relacion` type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.borrarrelacion AS
   (idborrar integer,
    paso integer,
    rel relacion);
```

Well, now into a function I need to copy some rows from a `relacion` type table to `borrarrelacion` type table:

This is a snippet of my code:

```
    DECLARE:
    r relacion%ROWTYPE;
    ------------

    BEGIN

    EXECUTE FORMAT ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mytable" OF borrarrelacion (PRIMARY KEY (idborrar))');
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE codpadre = %s AND codhijo = %s',
            tablarelacion,quote_literal(codigopadre),quote_literal(codigohijo)) INTO r;
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES(0,0,%s)',r);
```

But I get an error because the field `r.cancert` is NULL and it's trying to insert something like that:

`INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES(0,0,(0,'cod1','cod2',10,,0));`

I can solve this problem reading every field of `r` and putting it values in the INSERT statement, like that: (and changing the NULL value by 0)

```
EXECUTE FORMAT ('INSERT INTO "mytable" VALUES(0,0,(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))',
    r.id,quote_literal(r.codpadre),quote_literal(r.codhijo),r.canpres,COALESCE(r.cancert,0),r.posicion);
```

But I would like to know if I can avoid this way and I can insert exactly the same row from one table to other.

Comment: "But I get an error because the field r.cancert is NULL" - what error exactly do you get?

Comment: @eurotrash, I get something like that: INSERT INTO "algo" VALUES(0,0,(1,"CAP 1",P01,10.000,,0)) and ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL at all? None of the statements shown would require that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry. It's only a simplify example. The real problem create the tables dinamically and I need to use dynamic SQL